# How to index characters of string backwards in Java?

Tags: java, string, loops, indexing

I'm trying to make a program that checks for palindromes(words spelt the same forwards and backwards). I want to eventually compare the first char with the last char and the second char with the second to last char. I don't know what to put in the 'endingChar' string to make it check for that. Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String userPhrase;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in );

        System.out.println("Check for palindrome:");
        userPhrase = sc.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < userPhrase.length(); i++) {
            String currentChar = userPhrase.substring(i, i + 1);
            String endingChar = userPhrase.substring();

            System.out.println(currentChar);
            System.out.println(endingChar);
            //  if (userPhrase.indexOf(currentChar).equalsIgnoreCase(userPhrase.indexOf()))
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: check out the `String.charAt` method.  What index does the last character of a string w/ length `L` have?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to check for a palindrome would be to utilize [`StringBuilder.reverse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse%28%29):

```
boolean isPalindrome = userPhrase.equals(
            new StringBuilder(userPhrase).reverse().toString());

System.out.printf("[%s] is a palindrome? %b", userPhrase, isPalindrome);
```

Answer (score 0):

*Taken from [Here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/for-loop/check-for-palindrome-number-with-for-loop/), don't give me credit.

Here is some code for checking for a palindrome for integers. You could apply the logic to your code to make it work for strings as well:

```
// numbers to check

    int numbers[] = new int[]{ 252, 54, 99, 1233, 66, 9876 };



    // loop through the given numbers

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {



        int numberToCheck = numbers[i];

        int numberInReverse = 0;

        int temp = 0;



        // a number is a palindrome if the number is equal to it's reversed number



        // reverse the number

        while (numberToCheck > 0) {

            temp = numberToCheck % 10;

            numberToCheck = numberToCheck / 10;

            numberInReverse = numberInReverse * 10 + temp;

        }



        if (numbers[i] == numberInReverse) {

            System.out.println(numbers[i] + " is a palindrome");

        }

        else {

            System.out.println(numbers[i] + " is NOT a palindrome");

        }
```

Comment: Just post the links in the comments if you do not want to take credit from the Original Author

Comment: @YassinHajaj, I do not have the required reputation as of yet, or else I would have.

Answer (score 0):

You could rather use this

```
for(int i=0;;i++)
{
    if(i>=userPhrase.length-i)
        break;
    if(userPhrase.charAt(i)==userPhrase.charAt(userPhrase.length-i))
    {
        continue;
    }
        System.out.println("Not matched");
}
```